# Multithreading using Callable while having a responsive graphical interface

Tags: javafx, executorservice, callable, youtube-dl

I'm trying to get a responsive JavaFX graphical interface while executing a cmd command.
The command I'm executing is the following.

```
youtube-dl.exe --audio-format mp3 --extract-audio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2vy6pJSo9c
```

As you see this is a youtube-downloader that converts a youtube link to an mp3-file. 
I want this to be executed in a second thread and not in the main FX thread.

I've solved this by implementing interface `Callable` in the class `StartDownloadingThread`.

```
 @Override
public Process call() throws Exception {
     Process p = null;
     p = ExecuteCommand(localCPara1, localCPara2, localDirectory).start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30);
    }catch (InterruptedException e){}
    return p;
}
```

The method `ExecuteCommand` just returns a `ProcessBuilder` object.

I try to use `Thread.sleep` to make the program return to the main thread and thus making the application responsive. Unfortunately the program still freezes.

This is how the method call is called.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
StartDownloadingThread callable =  new StartDownloadingThread(parameter1, parameter2, directory);
Future future = pool.submit(callable);
Process p = (Process) future.get();
p.waitFor();
```

How do I make my GUI responsive using the interface `Callable`?

Answer (score 0):

Using a executor to run a task just for you to use the `get` method of the `Future` that is returned when submitting the task does not actually free the original thread to continue with other tasks. Later you even use the `waitFor` method on the original thread, which is likely to take even more time than anything you do in your `Callable`.

For this purpose the [`Task` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) may be better suited, since it allows you to handle success/failure on the application thread using event handlers.

Also please make sure an `ExecutorService` is shut down after you're done submitting tasks.

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        Process p = null;
        p = ExecuteCommand(localCPara1, localCPara2, localDirectory).start();

        // why are you even doing this?
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        }catch (InterruptedException e){}

        // do the rest of the long running things
        p.waitFor();
        return null;
    }
};
task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
    // modify ui to show success
});

task.setOnFailed(event -> {
    // modify ui to show failure
});
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

pool.submit(task);

// add more tasks...

// shutdown the pool not keep the jvm alive because of the pool
pool.shutdown();
```

Comment: I was actually reading the following tutorial. https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/j5e_multithreading.html#zz-7.5
About how to solve the Unresponsive User Interface. Section 7 in that article shows how you can do it by using Callable. The writer uses Thread.sleep() to return control to main thread.